# When using "quarto render" command, how can I print to the console in order to debug quarto reports?

Tags: quarto

I am using `quarto render` from the command line to generate reports using quarto. When I have a code block that contains an error, it is difficult to debug because I can't figure out how to print to the console when the rendering fails.

The only solution I have found is to comment out as much code and set as many code chucks to `eval: false` as I can while allowing the report to render successfully and then examine print statements that are output to the report.

This approach is time-consuming and inefficient. Is there a way to simply print() or message() or something directly to the console as the report is rendering, even if the report fails at some point after the print() statement?

```
---
title: "test report"
format: html
params:
  path: NULL
---
```

This code chunk will fail at read.csv but does not print params$path before exiting, so it is not possible to debug without commenting out `read.csv(params$path)` (In the code block below, I don't know how to include '````' fencing that would normally be present in a quarto document block since StackOverflow interprets the fencing in its markdown renderer)

````
```{r}
message(params$path)
print(params$path)

read.csv(params$path)
```
````

This is how I run the command.

```
quarto render my_report.qmd -P path:/my/bad/path
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using the chunk option `error: true`:

````
---
title: "test report"
format: html
params:
  path: NULL
execute: 
  error: true
---

```{r}
## this should work
message(params$path)
print(params$path)

# this should print the error message
read.csv(params$path)

## this should work again
2+2
```
````

[image]

If you want to print to console, I would use the `stop()` function.

Comment: The question was to print it to the console / terminal - not in the report. I have the same problem in a very long report - so observing the terminal and see the output from e.g. `message()` is much easier than going through the final report to find the errors.

Comment: Posted the question at the quarto discussion at https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/7443#discussion-5800619